PDFjs-dist - TypeError: Promise.withResolvers is not a function - Webpack Node JS
I've got the following "service" which is trying to extract the text from a PDF file but when it runs I am getting the same error every time no matter whether I point it at the main build (import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist";) or the legacy which was suggested as a fix. I have installed pdfjs-dist via npm and it is on version 4.3.136.
The error is:
TypeError: Promise.withResolvers is not a function
at new PDFDocumentLoadingTask (pdf.mjs:15693:31)
at Module.getDocument (pdf.mjs:15511:1)
at _callee$ (pdfJsService.js:23:23)
at tryCatch (pdfJsService.js:2:1)
at Generator.<anonymous> (pdfJsService.js:2:1)
at Generator.next (pdfJsService.js:2:1)
at asyncGeneratorStep (pdfJsService.js:2:1)
at _next (pdfJsService.js:2:1)
at pdfJsService.js:2:1
at initializePromise (es6-promise.js:437:1)

The code is:
import * as pdfjsLib from "pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.mjs";

// Specify the path to the worker script
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/4.3.136/pdf.worker.min.js`;

// Function to decode base64 string to Uint8Array
function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
  const binaryString = atob(base64);
  const len = binaryString.length;
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return bytes;
}

// Function to extract text from a base64 encoded PDF
export async function extractPdfText(base64String) {
  // Convert base64 string to buffer
  const pdfArray = base64ToUint8Array(base64String);

  try {
    const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: pdfArray }).promise;
    let extractedText = "";

    for (let i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {
      const page = await pdf.getPage(i);
      const textContent = await page.getTextContent();
      const textItems = textContent.items.map((item) => item.str).join(" ");
      extractedText += textItems + "\n";
    }

    console.log("extractedText ________+++++++++++++++++++++++++____________");
    console.log(extractedText);
    return extractedText;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing PDF: ", error);
  }
}

What do I need to do to get it to actually work?

It maybe your Node version is behind that with Promise.withResolvers, in which case you can polyfill for the missing function.
I'm on Node LTS (20.15.0) at time of writing and I don't have access to it either.  The following polyfill gets me past that stage:
// @ts-expect-error This does not exist outside of polyfill which this is doing
if (typeof Promise.withResolvers === 'undefined') {
  if (window)
      // @ts-expect-error This does not exist outside of polyfill which this is doing
      window.Promise.withResolvers = function () {
          let resolve, reject;
          const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
              resolve = res;
              reject = rej;
          });
          return { promise, resolve, reject };
      };
}


Thanks! This works on iOS 16 with PDFjs in CapacitorJS. Seems implemented in iOS 17.

I ran into this and than updated to node v22; i was on 18. before installind react-pdf package.
i use nvm to control node versions.
